# reactjs not able to perform put with axios

Tags: django, python-3.x, reactjs, react-redux

I am not able to perform put request in reactjs, redux and python django.

I have also gone through the one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982200/cannot-do-axios-put-request-in-django-restreact-framework-error-403) for the same in stackoverflow but no luck

Below is the action code when user click on button.

```
  export const updateAppTypeData = (appData) => async dispatch => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  var config = {

   };
  const response = await axios({
    method : 'put',
    url: ('http://localhost:8000/api/posts/appType/'+appData.id+'/'),
    data: appData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token}
  }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
  });
  //dispatch({ type : FETCH_APP_TYPE , payload: response.data });
};
```

Below is the Server side code for url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',ApkStatusView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',ApkStatusAPIDetailView.as_view()),
    url(r'^appType/$',AppTypeStatusView.as_view()),
    url(r'^appType/(?P<id>\d+)/$',AppTypeStatusAPIDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Server side code for view

```
class AppTypeStatusAPIDetailView(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    lookup_field            =   'id'
    permission_classes      =   [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class        =   AppTypeSeriializer
    queryset                =   Apptype.objects.all()


    def put(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def patch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def delete(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am getting the below issue.

```
PUT http://localhost:8000/api/posts/appType/1/ 403 (Forbidden)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
wrap @ bind.js:9
_callee3$ @ index.js:18
tryCatch @ runtime.js:62
invoke @ runtime.js:296
prototype.(anonymous function) @ runtime.js:114
step @ App.js:14
(anonymous) @ App.js:14
(anonymous) @ App.js:14
(anonymous) @ index.js:18
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
(anonymous) @ redux.js:449
ApkType._this.updateAppType @ apktype.js:60
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:201
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:461
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:480
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:581
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:592
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:562
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:723
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:732
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4477
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16660
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2131
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4556
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16715
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4533
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending the `token`, so you get back 403 `403 Forbidden`. add the token in the way your server expects it

Comment: Thanks @UXDart but after adding also I am getting the same result. I have updated the question.

Comment: the error is anyway 403, so the token is not being read by your server, check your server to see if the token gets there, and why is returning 403... your server is not reading the token, or is reading it, and anyway returning 403... that is an auth error

Comment: check here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ you need to use "WWW-Authenticate" headers

Comment: or "Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b"

Comment: try with `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Token '+token}`

Comment: I have tried this one Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b and updated the header but I don't know why server is still generating 403 response.

Comment: of course that was a token example... the one from the page, you need to use the 'Token '+token...

Comment: I have used what is given in the document i.e 'Token '+token but still getting error don't know where I am  getting wrong.