# How to send axios put request with jwt token in reactjs

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have tried to put details to server but getting 403 error

below is my code.

```
export const updateAppTypeData = (appData) => async dispatch => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  const response = await axios({
    method : 'put',
    url: ('http://localhost:8000/api/posts/appType/'+appData.id+'/'),
    data: appData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Token '+token},
    json: true
  }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
  });
  //dispatch({ type : FETCH_APP_TYPE , payload: response.data });
};
```

Any help will be a big plus. Thanks.

Comment: Your request options are correct IMO.

Comment: Thanks @Arup But still I am getting 403 error. Do we have to put jwt token in other fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing "Bearer" keyword in your header which is one of the allowed types (others are like like `basic` or `digest`).
Per [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) and [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

```
...
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Maielo but after trying this also it dosen't work.

Comment: if so it may be an error on your server side. You have somewhere checking for authentification and the API is returning you 403 forbidden because it can not read  jwt correctly ot something. Can you post how are you dealing with authentification/authorization on your server side ?

Comment: please check this link its having my server side details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970130/reactjs-not-able-to-perform-put-with-axios/51970425?noredirect=1#comment90893436_51970425